# How to set brightness over a SVG path element

Tags: css, svg

I want to apply brightness over a particular path element of SVG.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="top: 20px; left:15px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; background: none; width:528px; height: 418px;"
viewBox="32 0 470 432">
<defs>
 <style>
  .cls-1H{fill:#ed1c24}.cls-2H{fill:#ff7500; filter: brightness(2)}.cls-3H{fill:#82c341}.cls-4H{fill:#41d3ff}
</style>
</defs>
<path id="Path_139" d="M1314.486 1130.389l-8.164-5.659a257.023 257.023 0 0 0 24.271-43.518l9.1 3.973a267.1 267.1 0 0 1-25.207 45.204z" class="cls-1H" data-name="Path 139" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)"/>
<path id="Path_140" d="M1343.569 1075.834l-9.248-3.625a256.932 256.932 0 0 0 14.831-55.424l9.823 1.479a266.837 266.837 0 0 1-15.406 57.57z" class="cls-2H" data-name="Path 140" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)"/>
<path id="Path_141" d="M1360.292 1008.228l-9.873-1.1a257.522 257.522 0 0 0 1.591-28.53v-.421a261.5 261.5 0 0 0-1.55-28.435l9.875-1.084a271.611 271.611 0 0 1 1.608 29.52v.42a267.719 267.719 0 0 1-1.651 29.63z" class="cls-3H" data-name="Path 141" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)"/>
<path id="Path_142" d="M1349.213 940.075a256.583 256.583 0 0 0-14.7-55.44l9.255-3.606a266.481 266.481 0 0 1 15.268 57.591z" class="cls-4H" data-name="Path 142" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)"/>
</svg>
```

I am using `filter: brightness(2)` css property. This property is working fine if I apply over SVG element. But in path element, it's not working.
As per my requirement, I want to highlight particular path element conditionally.

Comment: There's no brightness filter in your markup. Just some text that says it doesn't work.

Comment: Brightness filter I am adding by javascript once the condition is a match, as you suggest I have added that property in one class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add `filter` css property on a `path` element. It won't work.

But you can use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) element and apply it on the `path` you want directly in the svg html code.

Play around with the `rgb` values so you get your desired result.

Read more here -> [feComponentTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComponentTransfer)

> performs color-component-wise remapping of data for each pixel. It allows operations like **brightness adjustment**, contrast adjustment, color balance or thresholding.

There's a good doc about it here -> [filters-to-adjust-brightness](https://vanseodesign.com/css/filters-to-adjust-brightness-contrast-opacity-and-inversion/)

> SVG filter is slightly more complex, though mainly to give you greater control, as it allows you to change the brightness of each color channel independently instead of changing all or none.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="top: 0px; left:15px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; background: none; width:528px; height: 418px;" viewBox="32 0 470 432" id="mySVG">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1H {
        fill: #ed1c24
      }

      .cls-2H {
        fill: #ff7500
      }

      .cls-3H {
        fill: #82c341
      }

      .cls-4H {
        fill: #41d3ff
      }

    </style>
  </defs>
  <filter id="my-filter">
    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2" />
      <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2" />
      <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2" />
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>

  <path id="Path_139" d="M1314.486 1130.389l-8.164-5.659a257.023 257.023 0 0 0 24.271-43.518l9.1 3.973a267.1 267.1 0 0 1-25.207 45.204z" class="cls-1H" data-name="Path 139" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)" />
  <path id="Path_140" d="M1343.569 1075.834l-9.248-3.625a256.932 256.932 0 0 0 14.831-55.424l9.823 1.479a266.837 266.837 0 0 1-15.406 57.57z" class="cls-2H" data-name="Path 140" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)" />
  <path id="Path_141"  filter="url(#my-filter)" d="M1360.292 1008.228l-9.873-1.1a257.522 257.522 0 0 0 1.591-28.53v-.421a261.5 261.5 0 0 0-1.55-28.435l9.875-1.084a271.611 271.611 0 0 1 1.608 29.52v.42a267.719 267.719 0 0 1-1.651 29.63z" class="cls-3H" data-name="Path 141" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)" />
  <path id="Path_142" filter="url(#my-filter)" d="M1349.213 940.075a256.583 256.583 0 0 0-14.7-55.44l9.255-3.606a266.481 266.481 0 0 1 15.268 57.591z" class="cls-4H" data-name="Path 142" transform="translate(-826.518 -710.46)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can add a brightness filter on a path in Firefox. It's a Chrome bug that it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Mihai T how can I add the same attribute (filter="url(#brightness)") in multiple path elements? I have added but other path elements are getting hide. Like: if I have two path element with the same color than how I can apply this attribute in two path element

Comment: @NeerajShrimali yes, i added it on the `green`  one and it works. add it without wrapping it in parentheses

Comment: If it doesn't work on Chrome you should a) report it so they know or b) vote on whatever existing ticket is tracking the implementation in the Chrome bugtracker so they know it's a feature people want.

Comment: And how would that solve the op's immediate problem ? Yes, you can do that but that wouldn't help me solving the op's problem. Here on SO ( as i am sure you know ) we help people solve problems by giving them a solution when there is one. And in this case, this is one of the solutions.

Comment: This is no longer true. CSS filter property can be added on path elements in Chrome just fine now. (Edit: presumably, you can still use SVG filters as normal, but you don't have to.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an svg filter for this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="top: 20px; left:15px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; background: none; width:528px; height: 418px;"
viewBox="1300 875 60 260">
<defs>

 <style>
  .cls-1H{fill:#ed1c24}.cls-2H{fill:#ff7500; }.cls-3H{fill:#82c341}.cls-4H{fill:#41d3ff; filter:url(#brightness)}
</style>

<filter id="brightness">
   <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncR type="linear" slope="2"></feFuncR>
        <feFuncG type="linear" slope="2"></feFuncG>
        <feFuncB type="linear" slope="2"></feFuncB>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</defs>
    
<path id="Path_139" d="M1314.486 1130.389l-8.164-5.659a257.023 257.023 0 0 0 24.271-43.518l9.1 3.973a267.1 267.1 0 0 1-25.207 45.204z" class="cls-1H" data-name="Path 139"/>
<path id="Path_140" d="M1343.569 1075.834l-9.248-3.625a256.932 256.932 0 0 0 14.831-55.424l9.823 1.479a266.837 266.837 0 0 1-15.406 57.57z" class="cls-2H" data-name="Path 140" />
<path id="Path_141" d="M1360.292 1008.228l-9.873-1.1a257.522 257.522 0 0 0 1.591-28.53v-.421a261.5 261.5 0 0 0-1.55-28.435l9.875-1.084a271.611 271.611 0 0 1 1.608 29.52v.42a267.719 267.719 0 0 1-1.651 29.63z" class="cls-3H" data-name="Path 141" />
<path id="Path_142" d="M1349.213 940.075a256.583 256.583 0 0 0-14.7-55.44l9.255-3.606a266.481 266.481 0 0 1 15.268 57.591z" class="cls-4H" data-name="Path 142" />
</svg>
```

Read more about the svg equivalents of css filters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter